# Speed up pgRouting point_to_id using new <-> operator in PostGIS 2.0.0

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, postgis-2.0, optimization

The point_to_id function, which assigns a node id to a point based on existing nodes and tolerance, is using a query as follows:

```sql
SELECT
id, the_geom
FROM vertices_tmp WHERE
    ST_DWithin(_p,the_geom, tolerance) 
ORDER BY ST_Distance(_p,the_geom) LIMIT 1;
```

This example is very similar to the one used to explain the [new KNN index based queries](http://blog.opengeo.org/2011/09/28/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/). I modified the query like this:

```sql
SELECT
id, the_geom
FROM vertices_tmp WHERE
    ST_DWithin(_p,the_geom, tolerance) 
ORDER BY _p <-> the_geom LIMIT 1;
```

However, as the documentation for '<->' says, the index kicks in only if one of the two operands is constant, as in ST_MakePoint(10,10).

Is there any trick to get the index to be used also in a function?

Comment: See the last comment on this question. Maybe it help.

[http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24456/nearest-neighbor-problem-in-postgis-2-0-using-gist-index-function][1]


  [1]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24456/nearest-neighbor-problem-in-postgis-2-0-using-gist-index-function

Answer (score 2):

For now, I resorted to using the new topology layers, using

```sql
UPDATE mytable 
SET source = topology.TopoGeo_AddPoint('nodes_topo', the_geom, 0.0001);
UPDATE mytable 
SET target = topology.TopoGeo_AddPoint('nodes_topo', the_geom, 0.0001);
```

Which adds also a new layer in which I can check the topology points' positions.
I wonder if those functions are optimized using the new KNN indexes, though.